# Збірка та збірник - поняття тотожні?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами, іменники

У [CУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zbirnyk) знайшла такі визначення:

> **збірник** - книжка, що містить у собі однорідні матеріали, документи і т. ін.
>
> **збірка** - книжка, яка містить у собі дібрані за певним принципом твори одного або кількох авторів.

Отже, чи можна назвати "Зів’яле листя" І. Франка збіркою та, водночас, збірником?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> **ЗБІ́РКА** (творів), ЗБІ́РНИК, ДОБІ́РКА (перев. невелика, зібрана за певною тематикою); **ЗІБРА́ННЯ** (перев. велике, повне). *Сьогодні здав до друку останню коректуру своєї збірки лірики* (А. Головко); *Воздвиженський взяв у руки збірник українських пісень і почав читати* (І. Нечуй-Левицький); *У своїй добірці я мав її [співанку] в двох відмінних варіантах* (І. Волошин); *Зібрання творів Т. Г. Шевченка.*

У [Словнику синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53399/265416.html) знаходимо:

> **ЗБІРКА**
>
> **збірник**, антологія; (шкільних текстів) читанка, хрестоматія; (творів) **зібрання**, (картин) колекція, збираниця; (статтей) кн. синопсис; (пожертв) Г. збіркова акція; ВІЙ. шикування, збір <н. в лаві збірка!>; З. збори.

Отже, ці слова є [семантичними (ідеографічними) синонімами](http://studopedia.com.ua/1_23817_sinonimi-v-ukrainskiy-movi.html).
Поради щодо цього слововживання можемо знайти [в «Уроках державної мови», що виходили в газеті «Хрещатик»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/26482.html):

> Збірка – однотомне (рідше кількатомне) видання художніх творів одного автора або фольклорних записів. Збірка поезій, збірка дум.
>
> Збірник – посібник з математики, фізики, мови тощо; книжка, що містить у собі різні матеріали, документи, зведені закони, тексти певного призначення; видання, до якого входять художні твори кількох чи багатьох авторів. Збірник задач, збірник диктантів; збірник наказів і розпоряджень, збірник новел молодих письменників.

Отже, ці слова є синонімами, але семантичними, тому в наведеному Вами прикладі потрібно казати збірка «Зів’яле листя» І. Франка.